# MySQL 8 Window Functions + Full-text searching

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I use mysql **Ver 8.0.3-rc** for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))

Create table and fulltext index on column **name**

```
CREATE TABLE `title` (
  `id` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  FULLTEXT idx (name) WITH PARSER ngram
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Insert some data:

```
insert into `title` values(14,"I'm flying in for the game (one night in Niagara Falls, NY and one night in Buffalo then back home).");
insert into `title` values(23,"I've never been to the area.");
insert into `title` values(43,"Where and what must I eat (Canadian side of Niagara, American side and Buffalo)?");
insert into `title` values(125,"Don't really have much planned other than the Falls and the game.");
```

When execute:

```
select
    id,
    round(MATCH (name) AGAINST ('other than the'),2) scope
from title;
```

Result (all ok):

```
id  | scope
----------
14  | 0.43
23  | 0.23
43  | 0.12
125 | 1.15
```

When use classic **GROUP BY** - all ok

```
select
    max(scope),
    min(scope),
    sum(scope)
from
(
    select id, round(MATCH (name) AGAINST ('other than the'),2) scope
    from title
) a;
```

result ok:

```
max  |  min | sum
----------------
1.15 | 0.12 | 1.96
```

But when i try use window function **over** i don't understand results:

```
select
    id,
    max(scope) over(),
    min(scope) over(),
    sum(scope) over()
from
(
    select id, round(MATCH (name) AGAINST ('other than the'),2) scope
    from title
) a;
```

I get a strange result (**WHY?**):

```
id | max  |  min | sum
------------------------
14 | 1.15 | 1.15 |  4.60
23 | 1.15 | 1.15 |  4.60
43 | 1.15 | 1.15 |  4.60
125| 1.15 | 1.15 |  4.60
```

I hope to get results similar to the classical group by, like:

```
id | max  |  min | sum
------------------------
14 | 1.15 | 0.12 |  1.96
23 | 1.15 | 0.12 |  1.96
43 | 1.15 | 0.12 |  1.96
125| 1.15 | 0.12 |  1.96
```

Is this a bug in mysql **Ver 8.0.3-rc** or incorrect my query?
Thanks!

Comment: Your result does seem strange to me.  I also would expect the same output you expect.

Comment: Your observation is correct. This is a bug which has been fixed after 8.0.3-rc went out. -Dag (MySQL dev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding wchiquito's answer: You are correct there is a bug. It has been fixed since release. After the fix, MySQL returns this answer to the windowing query:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->        `id`,
    ->        MAX(`scope`) OVER() `max`,
    ->        MIN(`scope`) OVER() `min`,
    ->        SUM(`scope`) OVER() `sum`
    ->      FROM
    ->      (
    ->        SELECT
    ->          `id`,
    ->          ROUND(MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('other than the'), 2) `scope`
    ->        FROM `title`
    ->      ) `a`;
+-----+------+------+------+
| id  | max  | min  | sum  |
+-----+------+------+------+
|  14 | 0.72 | 0.00 | 0.72 |
|  23 | 0.72 | 0.00 | 0.72 |
|  43 | 0.72 | 0.00 | 0.72 |
| 125 | 0.72 | 0.00 | 0.72 |
+-----+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0,01 sec)
```

which is still different from the one you quote from Maria; but I believe
the MySQL answer above is the correct one: since the window specification is empty, the window function should act on all the rows in the result set for each line, i.e. the same value should result for the window function calls on each result set line.

If you partition the result set similarly to what is done for the GROUP BY query (see PARTITION BY a.id in below), you will see this result:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->        `id`,
    ->        MAX(`scope`) OVER(PARTITION BY a.id) `max`,
    ->        MIN(`scope`) OVER(PARTITION BY a.id) `min`,
    ->        SUM(`scope`) OVER(PARTITION BY a.id) `sum`
    ->      FROM
    ->      (
    ->        SELECT
    ->          `id`,
    ->          ROUND(MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('other than the'), 2) `scope`
    ->        FROM `title`
    ->      ) `a`;
+-----+------+------+------+
| id  | max  | min  | sum  |
+-----+------+------+------+
|  14 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
|  23 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
|  43 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 125 | 0.72 | 0.72 | 0.72 |
+-----+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

because each row is its own partition here. This is the same as you quote for Maria *without the PARTITION BY*.

Comment: I already updated the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46848004/1316440). Definitely this has been an oversight on my part, the third `SELECT` of MariaDB section returns the expected result, see [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=88d4e48eac1bee76e576ec883af781c9). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have found a bug in MySQL, report bug: [bugs.mysql.com](https://bugs.mysql.com/).

I executed the following script in MySQL and MariaDB (without `WITH PARSER ngram` because currently in MariaDB it's not supported, see [Add "ngram" support to MariaDB](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10267)) with the result:

MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+--------------+
| VERSION()    |
+--------------+
| 8.0.3-rc-log |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `title`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `title` (
    ->   `id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `name` TEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    ->   FULLTEXT idx (`name`) -- WITH PARSER ngram
    -> ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `title`
    -> VALUES
    ->   (14, "I'm flying in for the game (one night in Niagara Falls, NY and one night in Buffalo then back home)."),
    ->   (23, "I've never been to the area."),
    ->   (43, "Where and what must I eat (Canadian side of Niagara, American side and Buffalo)?"),
    ->   (125, "Don't really have much planned other than the Falls and the game.");
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   MAX(`scope`),
    ->   MIN(`scope`),
    ->   SUM(`scope`)
    -> FROM
    -> (
    ->   SELECT
    ->     `id`,
    ->     ROUND(MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('other than the'), 2) `scope`
    ->   FROM `title`
    -> ) `a`;
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| MAX(`scope`) | MIN(`scope`) | SUM(`scope`) |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|         0.72 |         0.00 |         0.72 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   MAX(`scope`) OVER(),
    ->   MIN(`scope`) OVER(),
    ->   SUM(`scope`) OVER()
    -> FROM
    -> (
    ->   SELECT
    ->     `id`,
    ->     ROUND(MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('other than the'), 2) `scope`
    ->   FROM `title`
    -> ) `a`;
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | MAX(`scope`) OVER() | MIN(`scope`) OVER() | SUM(`scope`) OVER() |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  14 |                0.72 |                0.72 |                2.88 |
|  23 |                0.72 |                0.72 |                2.88 |
|  43 |                0.72 |                0.72 |                2.88 |
| 125 |                0.72 |                0.72 |                2.88 |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

MariaDB:

```sql
MariaDB[_]> SELECT VERSION();
+----------------------------------------+
| VERSION()                              |
+----------------------------------------+
| 10.2.6-MariaDB-10.2.6+maria~jessie-log |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `title`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB[_]> CREATE TABLE `title` (
         ->   `id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
         ->   `name` TEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
         ->   FULLTEXT idx (`name`) -- WITH PARSER ngram
         -> ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB[_]> INSERT INTO `title`
         -> VALUES
         ->   (14, "I'm flying in for the game (one night in Niagara Falls, NY and one night in Buffalo then back home)."),
         ->   (23, "I've never been to the area."),
         ->   (43, "Where and what must I eat (Canadian side of Niagara, American side and Buffalo)?"),
         ->   (125, "Don't really have much planned other than the Falls and the game.");
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB[_]> SELECT
         ->   MAX(`scope`),
         ->   MIN(`scope`),
         ->   SUM(`scope`)
         -> FROM
         -> (
         ->   SELECT
         ->     `id`,
         ->     ROUND(MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('other than the'), 2) `scope`
         ->   FROM `title`
         -> ) `a`;
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| MAX(`scope`) | MIN(`scope`) | SUM(`scope`) |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|         0.72 |         0.00 |         0.72 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> SELECT
         ->   `id`,
         ->   MAX(`scope`) OVER(),
         ->   MIN(`scope`) OVER(),
         ->   SUM(`scope`) OVER()
         -> FROM
         -> (
         ->   SELECT
         ->     `id`,
         ->     ROUND(MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('other than the'), 2) `scope`
         ->   FROM `title`
         -> ) `a`;
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| id  | MAX(`scope`) | MIN(`scope`) | SUM(`scope`) |
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  14 |         0.72 |         0.00 |         0.72 |
|  23 |         0.72 |         0.00 |         0.72 |
|  43 |         0.72 |         0.00 |         0.72 |
| 125 |         0.72 |         0.00 |         0.72 |
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```